# How to make a DBADB?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, maintenance

I recently seen a database server and it had a DBADB database. I asked the dba what it was for and he said he uses it to hold scripts so he has a central spot for them instead of using a network share or something like that.

Can someone tell me how to set one up. I have a lot of .sql script files I would like to store in a database as the team I work on keeps editing them and saving them, messing up the originals.

If someone could please tell me how to set one up that would be awesome!!!

Thank you

Comment: Have you heard of version control systems like [git](https://git-scm.com/)?

Comment: Yes but I would like to keep it in a database that away if I need to move it to a new server I can just move the database. Not real sure how to run/setup git but i'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

The question looks too broad, but in case you just want some guidance, here is a list of things that I imagine you need to know/have/do to achieve the final goal – have a usable database of scripts:

1. Obviously, you need access to a SQL Server instance (from anywhere in the network).
2. You need to have permissions to create a database (in case you are not logging in to the server as an administrator).
3. You need to (know how to) create a new database. (Consult the manual to find out how.)
4. How to store a script in a database? The most obvious choice to me would be a stored procedure. So create a stored procedure for every script in your new database. (Again, consult the manual.)
5. You need to know how to execute a stored procedure – provided you want to use the database to execute your scripts directly from it.
6. If you just want to store the scripts, you need to know how to retrieve the definition of an existing script/stored procedure, so that you can copy & paste the body and execute it in the required context. That will probably be the same knowledge that you will needed in order to alter an existing script.